# Is CPU Whining a Hardware defect?

Tags: cpu

I have some problem with my Fujitsu e746. It have some CPU Whining also known as coil Whining.

And now my Question, is this a Hardware defect? If you would ask me, I would say Yes. But i asked the Fujitsu Support and they said, „Sorry, We cant do anything because it not a Hardware defekt?

If it is a Hardware defect, could a Mainboard replace help?

Comment: [This is a CPU](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Intel_CPU_Core_i7_6700K_Skylake_top.jpg). It has no coils.

Answer (score 2):

Coil whine is dependent on the design of the board. All switch mode power supplies (the type used if you want any semblance of efficient power conversion) will "whine" at various frequencies as a feature of how they work.

Sometimes inductors may not be properly glued or the circuit might be slightly to one end or the other of tolerance and so may vibrate at audible frequencies more readily, but there is little evidence that an audible whine is any different to an inaudible one.

If it is louder than, say, your normal conversation volume then there may well be a problem but barely audible or close to a whisper is not considered a defect.

If you can hear it on the other side of a crowded room then something is seriously wrong. If you can *only* hear it close to the device in a silent room then it will be considered "normal" operation.

Granted that it *may* be a sign of slightly poor component choice or circuit design, which is often unavoidable due to design constraints, but that doesn't mean that the circuit won't do it's job for 5 or 10 years without problems.

It is also possible that what you are hearing might be being coupled into an audio circuit and amplified by your speakers. Again, at low volume this is not a defect as such but a fact of electronics design. Filtering out that kind of noise is actually quite difficult to do perfectly without additional circuitry.  Also again though, if it is loud when the system is muted then it *could* be a flaw or sign of failure.

Replacing the board *might* help if there is something out of specification or actually defective. You may well find that every board of that type has some level of coil whine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it's actually coil whining it's a hardware defect - a manufacturer might dispute that it's a defect at all, but if your support contact thinks it's software issue, you should assume the person reading your report didn't have their morning coffee yet and incorrectly guessed (instead of reading your report) that you're bothered by some software playing some annoying sounds.

It *might* be fixed with a mainboard replacement, a graphics card replacement, or a PSU replacement. A much better bet is to send it in under warranty. Make sure to specify that the noise isn't from the sound card, and that it's on the edge of the hearing range. Write for an elementary school kid. (e.g. "All my friends can hear the really high pitched whining noise, but my parents can't. The noise does not stop when the sound is turned off.  The noise comes from the laptop itself, not the speakers, not the fans. The noise only starts if the laptop is really busy.").

Alternatively you can go extremely technical, use only technical terms, and mention the measured pitch and dB of the noise in an attempt to get them to escalate the issue to someone technical who can make sense of the words you wrote.